# App Engine: submitting form data to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, gdata, google-sheets-api

We'd like to duplicate the Google Spreadsheet Form Wizard functionality within our App Engine application. The rational for this is that Google forms look ugly and the form wizard apparently does not provide enough hooks to make layout better.

Do you know any examples how to integrate Google Spreadsheet GData API in App Engine, so that the target spreadsheet and authentication tokens would be persistently stored? The spreadsheet is on our Google Apps domain, behind our own login and it should not be exposed to the site user in any point.

So we were thinking

1) Extract spreadsheet id and authentication token(s) from Google Spreadsheet API (how)

2) Store these in App Engine data store through App Engine console

3) Create a Django form and let our front-end developers to style it

5) Django form handler submits the results into the spreadsheet directly using GData API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you write makes sense, but where's the question?
You can put python gdata client library into your GAE project.
You can expose the spreadsheet (make it accessible from the outer world), but leave it private, so nobody would be able to manually access it, and authenticate your GAE Django app. Trivially - with plain auth behind SSL, byt better with OAuth, see gdata docs: http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_python.html

In order to get information for you spreadsheet - well, first manually create it, then from python code load documents list, it should have a single entry, dump its ID, and you will be able accessing it like 'spreadsheet:ID' from every method that expects Entry OR ID

You should also be (probably) able accessing it by URL passed to the same methods, bacuse I saw method parameter named entry_or_id_or_url.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to send data via Google Spreadsheet Forms ??